# How to instant redirect url in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I want to redirect a URL instantly in wordpress. This is my script code.

**JS CODE**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var x=window.location.href;

    if(x=='http://example.com/') {
        window.location.href='http://example.com/home';
    }
});
```

When I enter url example.com/, here I want it can instantly redirect to example.com/home without showing the example.com/ page. I want to see example.com/home page when I press enter on my site.

Comment: using php `header("Location: http://urlToRedirectTo/")` or .htaccess will be far better than js.

Comment: hey sir, give me an suitable example.

Comment: @Luke P's answer is a good example

Comment: ya but what can i write instead pagename.php, i need to move url to another url.

Comment: first result for "htaccess redirect domain to subfolder" on google : https://www.site5.com/blog/apache/htaccess/redirect-to-blog/

Answer (score 2):

It would be best to create the redirect in the htaccess file, something like this:

```
#Redirect a single page:
Redirect 301 /pagename.php http://www.domain.com/pagename.html
```

Comment: yes sir i agree, but i need only for this http://example.com/ to move to http://example.com/home. Not for the whole website. I think htaccess will move every url to http://example.com/home.

Comment: Have you tried it @kamalsoftphoton? If not, please do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) for redirect

**.htaccess file**

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /home/
```

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress provides a simple to use redirect function. Just place it at the very top of your template:

```
<?php
wp_redirect( 'http://example.com/home' );
exit;
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Comment: We think in the same way - I've just posted up almost the same answer without seeing your one! I think this user is just looking to redirect one page - that's why I added the front_page check

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this using the Wordpress framework itself is to use wp_redirect - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

So, you could hook into the wp action of wordpress (to make sure the $post item has been set and run the following. It will check if this is the Homepage of the site that is set in the Reading Settings and redirect if so.

It's not the optimum way to deal with this problem as it does load some of the page but it could be a quick temporary solution for your issue here. Just add this to you functions.php file

```
add_action('init','redirect_home');
function redirect_home(){
    if(is_front_page()||is_home()){
        wp_redirect(get_site_url().'/home');exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your htaccess file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /home [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?
```

Comment: it redirects all urls to same example.com/home. nothing opens other pages just goto /home url.